# How to remove an annoyance clickable body link with userscript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, greasemonkey, userscripts

Is there anyway to remove an annoyance clickable Ads body link?

Example:

```js
$('#test').ready(function(){ 
    $( 'body' ).click( function ( e ) {
        if ( this === e.target ) {
            window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
        }
    }); 
 });
```

```css
body { background: #f00; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width:100%; height:1000px; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            test
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all event listeners form an element by assigning its `outerHTML` to itself.

```
var body = document.body;
body.outerHTML = body.outerHTML;
```

But there is not way to remove one anonymous listener alone.

Comment: Sorry, annoyance not anonymous (text autocorrect error).

Comment: If you don't have a reference to the function then you can't remove it